# How to draw more two grid lines in a chart?

Tags: charts, jfreechart

I need to draw to more grid line in this chart below.
[image]

It should look like this, one more line in the top and another in the bottom.
[image]

How can I do this with JFreeChart ?

This is my code so far:

```
public JFreeChart draw(TimeSeriesCollection dataSet, StyleData styleData, Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle =   Internationalization.getPropertyResourceBundle("", locale)
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("", // Title
            "", // Time Axis Label
            "", // Value Axis Label
            dataSet, // XYDataSet
            false, // Legend
            false, // Tooltips
            false); // URLS

    Map<String, Color> colorMap = styleData.getColorMap();
    Map<String, Stroke> strokeMap = styleData.getStrokeMap();

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    chart.setBorderVisible(false);
    chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 10));

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    TS_General_Plot_Defaults.applyDefault(plot);

    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, colorMap.get("performance"));
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(0, strokeMap.get("series"));
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(colorMap.get("Background"));
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(colorMap.get("range-axis-grid"));
    plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(strokeMap.get("stroke"));
    plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);

    // Change Color of the Numbers Legends to Grey
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();

    rangeAxis.setTickLabelPaint(BLACK);
    rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(styleData.setupFontMap().get("Font"));
    rangeAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
    rangeAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
    rangeAxis.setTickUnit(getTickUnit(locale, rangeAxis.getRange().getLength()));

    DateAxis domainAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setTickLabelPaint(BLACK);
    domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(styleData.setupFontMap().get("Font"));
    domainAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);

    domainAxis.setTickUnit(getDateTickUnit(dataSet));
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(resourceBundle.getString("chart_date_pattern"));
    domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(formatter);

    return chart;
}
```

**EDIT:**

@DonCorleone, I can't draw a line above the `getUpperBound()` method and below the `getLowerBound()` method. See the picture below. Any idea how to do that ?

[image: chart-3]

This is my code using your suggestion:

```
        ValueMarker marker = new ValueMarker(rangeAxis.getLowerBound());  // position is the value on the Y axis
        marker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));
        marker.setPaint(Color.red);

        //add  to the plot
        plot.addRangeMarker(marker);

        marker = new ValueMarker(rangeAxis.getUpperBound());  // position is the value on the Y axis
        marker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));
        marker.setPaint(Color.red);

        //add  to the plot
        plot.addRangeMarker(marker);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a marker

```
                ValueMarker marker = new ValueMarker(position);  // position is the value on the Y axis

                marker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
                marker.setPaint(Color.black);

                XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

                //add  to the plot
                plot.addRangeMarker(marker);
```

Comment: You can change the color to your grid line color

Comment: The marker will be a horizontal line starting starting from Y-Axis at the value you define (position).

Comment: How can I get the position of my last (on the top) grid line ?

Comment: I think:             rangeAxis.getLowerBound();
                        rangeAxis.getUpperBound();

Comment: NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();

Comment: First you have to get the Y-AXIS ine rangeAxis.

Comment: I update my question, please take a look. And thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: I was thinking, can I add a one more range in my series ? Like, instead of trying to draw this two grid lines, my range shows the 40% and also the 220%.

Comment: You can use: rangeAxis.setUpperBound(value);

Comment: And rangeAxis.setLowerBound(value);

Comment: And define new range bounds. Then set the markers on these new bounds.

Comment: `rangeAxis.setUpperBound(rangeAxis.getUpperBound()+0.2);` and `rangeAxis.setLowerBound(rangeAxis.getLowerBound()-0.2);` solved the problem! :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice. You can make it more dynamic by using % of the upperbound

Comment: e.g rangeAxis.setUpperBound(rangeAxis.getUpperBound()+rangeAxis.getUpperBound()*0.1)